# memcpy on two-dimensional array

Tags: c

I am wondering if I am using the memcpy function right.

So I have a two-dim. array of strings, and when I try to fill them valgrind tells me

```
==825== Invalid write of size 8
==825==    at 0x344B8E: _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Unknown (in            /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==825==    by 0x1C4D74: __memcpy_chk (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==825==    by 0x100001328: generate_test_data (check_generate_test_data.c:4120)
==825==    by 0x100000CA6: main (check_generate_test_data.c:137)
==825==  Address 0x100030a00 is 0 bytes after a block of size 32 alloc'd
==825==    at 0x47F1: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:302)
==825==    by 0x100000FBB: generate_test_data (check_generate_test_data.c:4095)
==825==    by 0x100000CA6: main (check_generate_test_data.c:137)


 int i;
 char **test;
 int total = 4;
 int elements = 11;
 test = malloc(sizeof(char**)* total);
 for (i=0; i < total; i++) {
    // char *to_fill --//is filled with a method
    //  
    test[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * elements;    // <== here is where compiler complains
    memcpy(&test[i], &to_fill, strlen(to_fill);   // <== here is where valgrind complains
 }
```

When I change it to: 
      &test[i][0]

then the strings in test stay empty :S.. I also tried to remove the & of to_fill but with this my program just crashes.. I have no Idea what I am doing wrong here.

---

I changed all of the suggestions but the same error of valgrind appears, I even tried to put a constant char array into to_fill but still:

```
 int i;
 char **test;
 char *to_fill;
 int total = 4;
 int elements = 11;
 test = malloc(sizeof(char*)* total);
 to_fill = malloc(sizeof(char)* 100);
 to_fill[0] = '\0';
 for (i=0; i < total; i++) {
   //to_fill = method_to_fill_it(); 
   strncpy(to_fill, "example", 7);
   to_fill[7] = '\0';
   test[i] = malloc(sizeof(char*) * elements;
   memcpy(&test[i], &to_fill, strlen(to_fill);   // <== here is where valgrind complains
   to_fill[0] = '\0';
 }
```

Comment: You're calculating your malloc arguments based on the size of the *pointer*, not the type being *pointed to*.

Comment: Also, remember that the size of a string is (length+1)*sizeof(element).

Comment: You mean the first malloc? But how can I do it differently, I thought I first have to say how many char arrays I will have, so the first dimension (4), and then for each array, how many elements --chars it will get

Comment: I know, for the +1, already checked, and the "to_fill" array has an \0 at the last position, so strlen will not crash

Comment: The first malloc: `test = malloc(sizeof(char*)* total);` and the second: `test[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * elements;`

Comment: Is the to_fill array initialized?

Comment: A yes Igor you are right, I changed it, but the same complain of valgrind is still there :S

Comment: And yes the to_fill is initialised, fill it in every iteration, and at the end of the loop i do to_fill[0] = '\0'; to clear it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62040/discussion-between-igor-and-malajedala).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memcpy statement is wrong, you don't need to dereference a char pointer which  holds the address as it's value. Do this instead:

```
 memcpy(test[i], to_fill, strlen(to_fill));
```

When you do:

```
 memcpy(test[i], &to_fill, strlen(to_fill));
```

the memory address where `to_fill` is stored is passed to the function.

What you want to pass is the memory to which `to_fill`, the pointer, points to.

Comment: Oh YES IT WORKS FINALLY! Thank you so much. But can you please tell me why to write it that way?
I thought I have to pass to memcpy the source address and the destination address, I know that a char name is also the address of the first element, but shouldn't than both ways of writing work :S?